# How to design RESTful URI to get all unread messages?

Tags: asp.net, rest

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Web Api 2 with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have these entities in database:

- Users, which are members of groups.
- Groups.
- Messages. Users can sent messages to a groups.

I have this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GroupMessagesApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/groups/{groupId}/messages/{messageId}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "GroupMessages",
        messageId = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

With this route I can get all group's messages and **one message**, with `{messageId}`, sent to `{goupId}`.

But now I want to get **all messages** with an ID greater than `{messageId}`. How can I do that?

I've thought to create another route like this one:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GroupMessagesApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/groups/{groupId}/messages/{messageId}/unread",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "GroupUnreadMessages"
    }
);
```

I will need another controller, `GroupUnreadMessages, to get all unread messages. But I don't know if this is the better approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design RESTful Web Api to represent Resources](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/255794/how-to-design-restful-web-api-to-represent-resources)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I'm asking another thing. Please read all the question before say something. Both question are about the same URI, but each question are different.

Comment: @AndyBursh that's not really a duplicate. The question here is a more specific problem, most likely not covered there.

Comment: Why I will asking the same thing in two different questions? The another one is mine.

Comment: @VansFannel I would simply see this as a specific task of the already existing index action and just add a param to the url like ´from_message_id´. This at least unless the way you display this type of messages differs a lot from the normal index display.

Comment: @VansFannel it's not uncommon here that people post very similar or even identical questions multiple times. Often because they didn't get the expected answer the last times. And since questions once they leave the main page don't get that much attention anymore that happens often enough.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the greater than certain id query, probably clearest way is to use query strings. Something like

```
api/groups/{groupId}/messages?id=gt:50
```

The "gt:50" is just an idea, it is easy to parse but it can be anything you like (there is no > symbol in query strings, it is key value so you need to add your own operators if you want complex queries.

Your "messages" resource should return a sub-set of messages if it gets a query string, where as without the query string you get back all messages.

For all unread messages you could add another query string such as

```
api/groups/{groupId}/messages?status=unread
```

or you could make it part of the hierarchy.

```
api/groups/{groupId}/messages/unread
```

Depends on what makes sense for your resource hierarchy.